# Make a blur effect on canvas that is consistent across browsers

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, blur

On a HTML `<canvas>`, the only way to achieve a Gaussian blur is to use the [`shadowBlur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/shadowBlur) property.  However, the blur amount is inconsistent across browsers.

The difference is already apparent in the example on the [MDN documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/shadowBlur).

In Chrome:

[image: Chrome canvas]

In Firefox:

[image: Firefox canvas]

The blur is larger in Firefox as compared to Chrome.

Other ways (non-`canvas`) to create a Gaussian blur effect include:

- SVG [`<feGaussianBlur>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feGaussianBlur)
- CSS [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter) property

Both of them defines a blur using its standard deviation, thus achieving consistency across browsers.

There are ways to 'fake' a Gaussian blur on a canvas, such as using a carefully crafted [linear gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createLinearGradient), or by manipulating the image [pixel-by-pixel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData).

The ability to make a Gaussian blur seems to be something sorely lacking in the HTML canvas specification.  Is there any way to make the blur, perhaps with newer technologies?

Comment: Well you can use css filter on canvas too, so you can also use feGaussianBlur, but [browser support is not that great yet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter#Browser_compatibility). For highest compatibility, I would recommend [StackBlur.js](https://github.com/canvg/canvg/blob/master/StackBlur.js)

Comment: I just thought of something that might possibly work: Assuming that all browsers do a Gaussian blur with a standard deviation that is proportional to the value of the `shadowBlur` property, it would be possible to render a Gaussian blur using `shadowBlur` on an offscreen canvas and get the color of a predetermined pixel on the canvas, then do some math or binary search to find the proportionality constant.  This only needs to be done once on page load, so speed shouldn't be an issue.  I have yet to test if my assumption is correct.